# How to turn flet into APK?

Tags: python, flutter, build, apk, flet

How to turn a Flet Python APP into an APK?

I gave the command:
flet build apk --org com.example.myapp

Error: `flutter` command is not available in PATH. Install Flutter SDK.

Code:

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):
    page.title = "AlertDialog examples"

    dlg = ft.AlertDialog(
        title=ft.Text("Hello, you!"), on_dismiss=lambda e: print("Dialog dismissed!")
    )

    def close_dlg(e):
        dlg_modal.open = False
        page.update()

    dlg_modal = ft.AlertDialog(
        modal=True,
        title=ft.Text("Please confirm"),
        content=ft.Text("Do you really want to delete all those files?"),
        actions=[
            ft.TextButton("Yes", on_click=close_dlg),
            ft.TextButton("No", on_click=close_dlg),
        ],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END,
        on_dismiss=lambda e: print("Modal dialog dismissed!"),
    )

    def open_dlg(e):
        page.dialog = dlg
        dlg.open = True
        page.update()

    def open_dlg_modal(e):
        page.dialog = dlg_modal
        dlg_modal.open = True
        page.update()


    page.add(
        ft.ElevatedButton("Open dialog", on_click=open_dlg),
        ft.ElevatedButton("Open modal dialog", on_click=open_dlg_modal),
    )


ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")
```

Comment: As the error suggested, you need to [install Flutter SDK](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install).

Comment: I have already downloaded the Flutter SDK and created the environment variable.

How do I point, in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 0):

In your shell, run the following

```bash
# (ubuntu 22.04)
sudo snap install flutter --classic

# (ubuntu 22.04)
sudo apt install android-sdk sdkmanager

# build for android:
sudo -E flet build apk

# at debian: 
sudo apt install snapd
```

then follow the first steps.
the `()` is because I only tested at that distro.

Answer (score 0):

look at: https://flet.dev/docs/guides/python/packaging-app-for-distribution

you need install flet android build dependencies:
flutter SDK, android studio, so on.

setup ANDROID_HOME enviroment variable.

hope this helps. bye.